# Post gallery as carousel

Tags: posts, loop, page-template, gallery

So I have this idea in mind: I would like to create custom page template, and whenever in post gallery is between tags, for example:

```
Lorem ipsum somethinginkgsd....

[carousel]
Gallery here
[/carousel]
```

I would like to convert this gallery to a carousel.

Creating carousel is fairly simple I guess. I just need something like get_post_gallery_images, but:

- get_post_gallery_images will only return first gallery in post
- this would still render gallery inside a post.

So my question is: how to get exactly the one gallery between [carousel] tags, and how to replace it?

Thank you a lot for any help!

Comment: which gallery you want to display and what have you tried yet

Answer (score 0):

Use the same [gallery shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) generated in the visual editor, then add an attribute to note carousel. That way you piggyback on all the functionality with very little extra effort required.

```
 [gallery carousel="true" link="none" size="medium" ids="378,377,376,375,374,373"]
```

See this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212122/84219) for how to approach this by replacing the default gallery shortcode.