# Turn Shortcode Gallery into Carousel in WordPress 4.4

Tags: plugin-development

I searched for existing plugins that could do carousels in wordpress posts but they turned out to not display correctly in WordPress 4.4 which released recently.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/agnosia-bootstrap-carousel/

Is there a carousel option available that makes it easy to add captions/images/links and the number of columns for WordPress posts compatible with the latest release?

Or is it possible to add a custom script to extend the existing gallery shortcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can piggyback off of the [WP Gallery shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) to render your slider. This example is adapted from the [Owl Carousel Demo](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html) / [Docs](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to).

To use it, create a [WP Gallery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) and add the attribute `owl="true"`. Obviously there are better ways to [enqueue scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) but this can guide you on gallery modifications.

---

```
 [gallery owl="true" link="none" size="medium" ids="378,377,376,375,374,373"]
```

---

**NOTE**: It's best to put this shortcode in a plugin but it's possible to add to your `functions.php` -- at that point it will be theme specific. If you apply to a default theme and update then these changes will be overwritten. You have been warned.

For an easy location put it into `wp-content/mu-plugins/gallery-owl-shortcode.php`. It will always load and you don't need to make a full plugin.

---

**UPDATE**:

I realized this code could repeat a lot of JS and CSS on a blog page if every post had gallery so I added a check to see if that portion has already been included. The downside is that all galleries have the same settings.

---

```
<?php

add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'modified_gallery_shortcode' );

function modified_gallery_shortcode($attr)
{
    // Replace WP gallery with OWL Carousel using gallery shortcode -- just add `owl=true`
    //
    // [gallery owl="true" link="none" size="medium" ids="378,377,376,375,374,373"]

    if( isset($attr['owl']))
    {
        $attr['itemtag']="span";

        $output = gallery_shortcode($attr);

        $output = strip_tags($output,'<a><img><span><figcaption>'); // remove extra tags, but keep these
        $output = str_replace("span", "div", $output); // replace span for div -- removes gallery wrap
        $output = str_replace('gallery-item', "item", $output); // remove class attribute

        $output = "<div class=\"owl-demo\" >$output</div>"; // wrap in div

        // begin styles and js

        static $js_loaded; // only create once
        if( empty ( $js_loaded )) {

        ob_start();
        ?> 
        <style>
            .owl-demo .item{
                margin: 3px;
            }
            .owl-demo .item img{
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script defer src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery('head').append('<link defer id="owl-carousel-css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css" />');
            jQuery('head').append('<link defer id="owl-theme-css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" type="text/css" />');

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                // pulling example from -- including CSS
                // http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

                // notice I replaced #id with .class for when you want to have more than one on a page
                jQuery(".owl-demo").owlCarousel({

                    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

                    items: 1,
                    itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
                    itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 1] // adaptive image count
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        $js_loaded = ob_get_clean(); // store in static var

        // add the HTML output
        $output .= $js_loaded;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // default gallery
        $output = gallery_shortcode($attr);
    }

    return $output; // final html
```

---

**ALTERNATE**

So the above code works but it might be nice to create a completely new interface rather than hacking at the gallery that WP provides. Since the IDs are passed in the attributes you can build your own solution from scratch -- including a custom link -- just make sure to register the link field.

```
if( isset($attr['owl']))
{
    $image_ids = explode(',', $attr['ids']);

    $output = '';
    $size = isset($attr['size']) ? $attr['size'] : 'medium';

    foreach($image_ids as $attachment_id) {

        // http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/how-to-retrieve-an-image-attachments-alt-text

        $img_src = '';//esc_url(  wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, $size ) );
        $img_srcset = esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, $size ) );

        $alt = esc_attr ( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) );
        $link = esc_attr ( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_gallery_link_url', true) );
        $the_attachment = get_post($attachment_id); // post
        $caption = esc_attr ( $the_attachment->post_excerpt );

        $img = "<img src=\"{$img_src}\" srcset=\"{$img_srcset}\"
             sizes=\"auto\" alt=\"{$alt}\">";
        $link = empty($link) ? $img : "<a href=\"{$link}\" >{$img}</a>";
        $caption = "<figcaption>{$caption}</figcaption>";
        $item = "<div class=\"item\">{$link}{$caption}</div>";

        $output .= $item;
    }

    $output = "<div class=\"owl-demo\" >$output</div>"; // wrap in div

    //... include JS & CSS stuff
}
```

Register [Custom Link field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/) on gallery attachment

```
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'apply_filter_attachment_fields_to_edit', null, 2 );
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'apply_filter_attachment_fields_to_save', null , 2 );
function apply_filter_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post )
{
    // Gallery Link URL field
    $form_fields['gallery_link_url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Gallery Link URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true ),
    );
    return $form_fields;
}

function apply_filter_attachment_fields_to_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    // Save our custom meta fields
    if( isset( $attachment['gallery_link_url'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_gallery_link_url', $attachment['gallery_link_url'] );
    }
    return $post;
} // End function apply_filter_attachment_fields_to_save()
```

Comment: I placed the file in wp-content/mu-plugins/gallery-owl-shortcode.php and it worked!

Comment: Great 'hack', but do you have any idea why is the css showing in `.owl-demo` container? `#gallery-1 {
    margin: auto;
   }
   #gallery-1 .item {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
   }
   #gallery-1 img {
    border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
   }
   #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
    margin-left: 0;
   }
   /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */`

Comment: Figured it out. I had to add `<style>` to: `$output = strip_tags($output,'<a><img><span><figcaption><style>');`