# Allowing for multiple template views on the Gallery Settings page when using the Visual Editor

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, gallery, customization, media-settings

I'm trying to extend this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212121/turn-shortcode-gallery-into-carousel-in-wordpress-4-4/212122#212122) by making it possible to switch shortcode attributes from the UI and alter the gallery markup based on those attributes.

```
[gallery owl="true" link="none" size="medium" ids="378,377,376,375,374,373"]
```

In this case, if `owl` is set to `true` then an [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com) would render in the gallery's place - which is does. But like any shortcode you have to remember the correct attributes. Seeing that I also want the ability to swap carousels to say [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/) then the attribute `owl` is limited and hard to remember based on the supported feature set.

Luckily for me I found a snippet to add ~custom fields~ to the gallery using this [sample](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-fields-to-gallery-settings).

```
add_action('print_media_templates', function(){

  // define your backbone template;
  // the "tmpl-" prefix is required,
  // and your input field should have a data-setting attribute
  // matching the shortcode name
  ?>
  <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-custom-gallery-setting">
    <label class="setting">
      <span><?php _e('My setting'); ?></span>
      <select data-setting="my_custom_attr">
        <option value="foo"> Foo </option>
        <option value="bar"> Bar </option>
        <option value="default_val"> Default Value </option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </script>

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      // add your shortcode attribute and its default value to the
      // gallery settings list; $.extend should work as well...
      _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
        my_custom_attr: 'default_val'
      });

      // merge default gallery settings template with yours
      wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
               + wp.media.template('my-custom-gallery-setting')(view);
        }
      });

    });

  </script>
  <?php

});
```

Unfortunately the post is > 2 years old and closed.

The **challenge** is: if I replace the template view with my settings then it's impossible to extend the settings set from another plugin or theme. The last view set as `template:` is always the winner.

The **question**: How can I code this to allow for greater flexibility, where by not only my settings show but I also don't block the ability for other  plugins / theme modifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the templates live in script form

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-custom-gallery-setting">
```

To render the above template would require

```
wp.media.template('my-custom-gallery-setting')(view)
```

Since we're replacing the `template:` logic then all we need to do is store a list of template IDs.

```
if (!wp.media.gallery.templates) wp.media.gallery.templates = ['gallery-settings'];
wp.media.gallery.templates.push('my-custom-gallery-setting');
```

Then loop through all available views

```
wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
    template: function (view) {
        var output = '';
        for (var i in wp.media.gallery.templates) {
            output += wp.media.template(wp.media.gallery.templates[i])(view);
        }
        return output;
    }
});
```

---

**RESULT**

So now the client doesn't have to remember shortcode attributes in order to modify the gallery because all options have been added to the UI as dropdowns.

```
[gallery link="none" type="owl" shape="square" ids="7228,7227,7226,7128,7127"]
```

As a bonus, the list of supported types are passed through a filter so you can add or reduce the amount of choices from a third-party source.

[image]

**LOCATION A**

```
add_action('print_media_templates', function() {

    // define your backbone template;
    // the "tmpl-" prefix is required,
    // and your input field should have a data-setting attribute
    // matching the shortcode name
    $gallery_types = apply_filters('print_media_templates_gallery_settings_types',
                                   array(
                                       'swiper'      => ' Swiper',
                                       'owl'         => ' Owl Carousel',
                                       'revolution'  => ' Revolution Slider',
                                       'default_val' => ' Default'));
    ?>
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-type-setting">
        <label class="setting">
            <span><?php _e('Layout Type'); ?></span>
            <select data-setting="type"><?php
                foreach($gallery_types as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </script>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            // add your shortcode attribute and its default value to the
            // gallery settings list; $.extend should work as well...
            _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
                type: 'default_val'
            });

            // join default gallery settings template with yours -- store in list
            if (!wp.media.gallery.templates) wp.media.gallery.templates = ['gallery-settings'];
            wp.media.gallery.templates.push('custom-gallery-type-setting');

            // loop through list -- allowing for other templates/settings
            wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
                template: function (view) {
                    var output = '';
                    for (var i in wp.media.gallery.templates) {
                        output += wp.media.template(wp.media.gallery.templates[i])(view);
                    }
                    return output;
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
    <?php
});
```

**LOCATION B**

```
add_action('print_media_templates', function() {

    // define your backbone template;
    // the "tmpl-" prefix is required,
    // and your input field should have a data-setting attribute
    // matching the shortcode name
    $gallery_types = apply_filters('print_media_templates_gallery_settings_shapes',
                                   array(
                                       'circle'      => ' Circle',
                                       'rectangle'   => ' Rectangle',
                                       'square'      => ' Square',
                                       'default_val' => ' Default'));
    ?>
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-shapes">
        <label class="setting">
            <span><?php _e('Shapes'); ?></span>
            <select data-setting="shape"><?php
                foreach($gallery_types as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$key\">$value</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </script>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            // add your shortcode attribute and its default value to the
            // gallery settings list; $.extend should work as well...
            _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
                shape: 'default_val'
            });

            // join default gallery settings template with yours -- store in list
            if (!wp.media.gallery.templates) wp.media.gallery.templates = ['gallery-settings'];
            wp.media.gallery.templates.push('custom-gallery-shapes');

            // loop through list -- allowing for other templates/settings
            wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
                template: function (view) {
                    var output = '';
                    for (var i in wp.media.gallery.templates) {
                        output += wp.media.template(wp.media.gallery.templates[i])(view);
                    }
                    return output;
                }
            });

        });

    </script>
    <?php
});
```